# model.set does not persist values in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
this.save(userDetails, {
    success: function (user, result, xhr) {
        this.set({userName: user.userName});
    },

    error: function (user, result, xhr) {

    }
});

return this.userName;
```

When i try to set my `userName` with the response i get, it does not set. When i try to alert return `this.userName`, it says me undefined.

Comment: one imp q is , even with your logic why would you do a model.set after saving the model , btw the model is set with the values when you save

Comment: @user1537158: can u look at this pastie and let me know

Comment: which pastie ? , you mean the code in the question ?

Comment: @user1537158: added the pastie... just look i all need to do a return once the login is finished... everything works fine except the return

Comment: just to see what the save(model) returns do this : console.log(JSON.stringify(model)); you will understand the data-structure and the data of what is returned

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24013/discussion-between-thejava-and-user1537158)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Couple of things here :

1. When the success function is called (the call back after save) , it return the entire model that is saved , so you might try :

   success : function(model){
   model.set({userName : model.userName});
   }
2. The save is asynchronus , so you might want to do something like :

   this.model.on('sync',function(model){
   model.set({userName : model.userName});
   //rest of programming;
   })

Comment: function(model){ model.set({userName : model.userName}); } there is no point doing that since the model.userName  is already set to userName when the model is saved. this.userName will return undefined,because , this is a backbone model and cant access its datas directly

Comment: which one should i follow... the first or second one... what about the success handler.

Comment: @mpm: how can i return the userName back to my controller... i know u can't do it from success handler.

Comment: there is no controllers in backbone , i dont know what you are talking about.

Comment: @mpm , apollogies for being a little off ,

a. model.get("userName") would do it for you
b. theJava do you mean the View ? in place of controller

Answer (score 1):

`user` is the Backbone model, so essentially it seems like you are trying to do this:

`user.set({userName: user.get('userName'});`

If userName is a value that comes back from your server, it is probably already set on the model.

In your success handler, try this:

`console.log(user.get('userName'));`

You do not access a model's attributes using `model.userName`, you use `model.get('userName')`.

Comment: I am getting the value, but when i try to return this.userName at the end it does not work.

Comment: There is no `this.userName` unless you are setting it somewhere in code you did not post.

Comment: we set the userName to our Model... can't i access my model through this reference.

Comment: Again, `model.get('userName')`, not `model.userName`.